# use number of solutions rather than maximum time to end solve attempts

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

I am using the CP-SAT solver on a JSP.

I am iterating so the solver runs many times (basically simulating each day for a year), I do not need to find the optimal solution, just a reasonably good one, so I would like to be a bit smarter on ending the solver than simply allowing it to run for X seconds each time. For example, i would like to take the 5th solution each time, or even to stop once the current solution makespan is only 5% (for example) shorter than the previous solution.

Is this possible? I am only aware of `solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds` as a way of limiting the calculation time. Intermediate solutions are printed by `SolutionPrinter` but i think this is output only and there is no way to break the solver during a run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong, you can stop the search in a callback, see this recipe:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/docs/solver.md#stopping-search-early